# Deleting table row with animation using core data

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, delete-row

If I delete a row from my table using a standard animation such as `UITableViewRowAnimationFade`  the code crashes with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 1.  The
>   number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (4)
>   must be equal to the number of rows
>   contained in that section before the
>   update (4), plus or minus the number
>   of rows inserted or deleted from that
>   section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

If I remove the animation line the row removal/deletion works, but I no longer have the cool Apple delete transition.

Here is my code - any help is appreciated. This method of deleting rows worked prior to *iOS4*, not sure if something has changed?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
        MyItem *myItem = [self.getItemsFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
        [dataRepository deleteItem:myItem];

        // If I comment this line out the delete works but I no longer have the animation
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

}
```

**Data Repository**:

```
-(void)deleteItem:(MyItem *)myItem {
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:myItem];
    [self saveCurrentContext];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this issue by using this code before and after the table update:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    ... 
}
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I tried doing this but its still not working for me. Please help

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this could be if you have set `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and implemented `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` It will be called when you save the context and update the table view on your behalf. You might have code like this:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
```

Generally when you get the error it means that you have not updated the data source in the way you specified with `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. When you call that method you guarantee that you have already updated the data source to reflect that change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have not implemented NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate - this sounds like something I should look into.  I managed to fix my issue and have posted the answer