# How to update UITableView cells when user swipe and see 'Delete' button?

Tags: ios, uitableview, timer

I have `UITableVIew` table.

I implemented deleting in method `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` of `UITableViewDataSource` Protocol.

All work fine here.
Useful question on subject here [Deleting table row with animation using core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276804/deleting-table-row-with-animation-using-core-data) .

But every cell shows timer which count down and I have issue with this.

I use `NSTimer` in following way:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self
    selector:@selector(updateTickerHandler:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

...

```
- (void)updateTickerHandler:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

When user swipes to delete timer, button "Delete" disappear when `[tableView reloadData];` called.

I want to implement updating timer count down values on table cells which allows user to use swipe with "Delete" smoothly.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to obtain working behaviour with the call:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

The working solution is to update cell components manually and not to call `[table reloadData]`

Code of `updateTickerHandler:` could be updated in the following way:

```
- (void)updateTickerHandler:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];


    // select visible cells only which we will update 
    NSArray *visibleIndices = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    // iterate through visible cells
    for (NSIndexPath *visibleIndex in visibleIndices)
    {
        MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell*)
            [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:visibleIndex];

        // add here code to fill `cell` with actual values
        // visibleIndex can be used to retrieve corresponding data

        ...
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)updateTickerHandler:(NSTimer*)timer
{
 [Table beginUpdates];
 [Table reloadData];
 [Table endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: this does not fix the issue. What does it mean 'Table'?